# Compare List of Tuples and Return Indices of Matched Values

Tags: python, tuples

I'm new to programming and am having some trouble with this exercise. The goal is to write a function that returns a list of matching items.

Items are defined by a tuple with a letter and a number and we consider item 1 to match item 2 if:

1. Both their letters are vowels (aeiou), or both are consonants

AND

2. The sum of their numbers is a multiple of 3

***NOTE: The return list should not include duplicate matches --> (1,2) contains the same information as (2,1), the output list should only contain one of them.***

Here's an example:

```
***input:*** [('a', 4), ('b', 5), ('c', 1), ('d', 3), ('e', 2), ('f',6)]

***output:*** [(0,4), (1,2), (3,5)]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = [('a', 4), ('b', 5), ('c', 1), ('d', 3), ('e', 2), ('f',6)]
vowels = 'aeiou'
matched = [(i[0],j[0]) for (i,j) in combinations(enumerate(lst),2) if (i[1][0] in vowels) == (j[1][0] in vowels) and ((i[1][1] + j[1][1]) % 3 == 0)]
print(matched)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm high enough rep to comment, but i'll edit / update once I can.

Im a little confused about the question, what is the purpose of the letters, should we be using their positon in the alphabet as their value? i.e a=0, b=1?

what are we comparing one tuple to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations` with `enumerate` to iterate all combinations and output indices. Combinations do not include permutations, so you will not see duplicates.

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = [('a', 4), ('b', 5), ('c', 1), ('d', 3), ('e', 2), ('f',6)]

def checker(lst):
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    for (idx_i, i), (idx_j, j) in combinations(enumerate(lst), 2):
        if ((i[0] in vowels) == (j[0] in vowels)) and ((i[1] + j[1]) % 3 == 0):
            yield idx_i, idx_j

res = list(checker(lst))

# [(0, 4), (1, 2), (3, 5)]
```